# PayPal Pro - how to remove link to paypal

Tags: drupal, paypal

I have civicrm 4.6.10 installed under drupal 7.41 and we paid extra for PayPal Pro to avoid linking to paypal (i.e. leave the site). How do I remove the button that lets you link to PayPal? The rest works fine.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that part of your agreement with PayPal is to offer the option to pay with PayPal.  While you could use jQuery to hide the button or alter CiviCRM's code to remove it from display, you've promised PayPal that you won't.

There are stories (urban legends or actual instances, I'm not sure) of PayPal going after folks who hide the Pay with PayPal button.

Even if you don't care about that, CiviCRM will never remove the button so long as it's required by the agreement, so any code you write will have to be maintained as you upgrade.  This is a real cost that you should weigh against this.

Separately, we have clients who swear that many of their donors *prefer* to use PayPal, so that's another reason to leave it as-is.

Comment: Thanks for responding Andrew.   My understanding of PayPal PRO is that the reason for paying extra for PRO is to keep from going to PayPal and back.  With civiCRM using PayPal PRO, the option has already been selected to use PayPal.  The fact that we are paying $0.30 +++ a fee is to keep the cilent on the site (while still using paypal).

Comment: Could perhaps use the Test Processor and just fill in all paypal pro fields instead except the button link  ?  No link to paypal (I haven't tried that). I could also select an icon of my own that does not link anywhere - I will try that next.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a Simple answer -

The button image is the last entry at the bottom of your paypal pro payment processor setup page and I removed the button url image that would display on the link for the user to access paypal. The setting lets you enter the button image to use (select one from Papal's list of image urls). If not there, then no button is displayed but the link is still available and now it has a fuzzy description - and all the credit card images disappeared. I expected it to do "nothing".

I'm going to look for a way to hide the button/link.

Any other suggestions?